# iOS: How to use a button to switch a Tableview row?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, button, uiview

I'm making an app in which i have a Tableview that loads when the app starts. After I click on a row I get to a view with a navigation controller and a toolbar. On the tool bar I have made two buttons for back and forward (a back arrow and a forward arrow). How can I code these buttons to select the next and previous rows of the table (back for previous row, forward for next row)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to make your table view controller a delegate of the detail view controller, then define a delegate protocol to tell the delegate when those buttons were pressed. That way the table view controller can do whatever it needs to with the table view.

One way to do this:

```
@implementation MyTableViewController
...
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)p {
    MyDetailViewController *vc = [[MyDetailViewController alloc] initWithRow:p.row];
    // configure vc
    vc.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
}

- (void)myDetailViewControllerDidSelectPrevious:(MyDetailViewController *)vc {
    // use vc.row-1 to update the view controller or push a new one
}
- (void)myDetailViewControllerDidSelectNext:(MyDetailViewController *)vc {
    // use vc.row+1 to update the view controller or push a new one
}
@end

@protocol MyDetailViewControllerDelegate
- (void)myDetailViewControllerDidSelectPrevious:(MyDetailViewController *)vc;
- (void)myDetailViewControllerDidSelectNext:(MyDetailViewController *)vc;
@end
@implementation
...
- (void)nextButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate myDetailViewControllerDidSelectNext:self];
}
- (void)previousButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate myDetailViewControllerDidSelectPrevious:self];
}
@end
```

Comment: I don't know how to use a detail view controller yet :(

Comment: OK, I will update my answer with a real example, in the meantime read [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it when I get a chance.